# Flask-RESTful custom routes other than GET,PUT,POST,DELETE

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

In Flask-RESTful we add an api route like the below

```
api.add_resource(CuteKitty,'/api/kitty')

class CuteKitty(Resource):
    def get(self): return {}
    def post(self): return {}
    def put(self): return {}
    def delete(self): return None, 204
```

so that `GET /api/kitty` --> to `CuteKitty.get()` method; like this for all HTTP verbs

Lets say that I need to provide my api consumers with a cute api like

```
POST /api/kitty/drink/milk  ---> CuteKitty.drink(what="milk")
POST /api/kitty/meow        ---> CuteKitty.meow()
```

How can i achive the above routing with `api.add_resource`

```
class CuteKitty(Resource):
    def get(self): return {}
    def post(self): return {}
    def put(self): return {}
    def delete(self): return None, 204
    def drink(self,what="milk"): return {}
    def meow(self): return {}
```

Like wise how to add route like `/api/kitty/<int:kitty_id>/habits` --> `CuteKitty.habits(kitty_id)`

Comment: Cracking up over the example! :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Flask-RESTful is designed to implement RESTful APIs specifically by interpreting the HTTP Request method. Drink and Meow are not standard HTTP methods so Flask-RESTful isn't concerned with the `drink` and `meow` methods in the resource.

The solution to this is to define multiple API routes:

```
api.add_resource(CuteKitty, '/kitty/<int:kitty_id>/')
api.add_resource(DrinkingKitty, '/kitty/<int:kitty_id>/drink/<what>')
api.add_resource(MeowingKitty, '/kitty/<int:kitty_id>/meow/')
```

The less intuitive (and imo far worse) way is by creating a frankenresource:

```
# still allow requests to hit just get/post/etc without invoking anything else
api.add_resource(CuteKitty, '/kitty/<int:kitty_id>/')
api.add_resource(CuteKitty, '/kitty/<int:kitty_id>/<task>/<path:args>/')
```

And then break the args with `split('/')` and call task with them. Alternatively, you could set these as URL arguments (`/endpoint/?task=drink&what=milk`) -- which is still a valid RESTful architecture.

You could also subclass the Resource class and implement the desired functionality yourself -- in this case, I'd recommend looking at how Flask-Classy implements this. Or you could pick up Flask-Classy and toy with it and see how you like that, too; however, for a straight up API I think RESTful brings a lot more to the table than Classy.

Comment: This clears a lot of confusion I had, but I just thought that if by any chance I can have all the code belonging to `CuteKitty` in a single file/class, it seems the REST-ful does not allow that. I also don't what to write lot of boiler plate code myself for `/endpoint/<id>/<task>/<args>`. I guess I will stick with writing many class as of now. Thanks @justanr!

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Write the Resource class.

```
class CuteKitty(Resource):
   def get(self): return {}
   def post(self): return {}
   def put(self): return {}
   def delete(self): return None, 204
   def meow(self): return {}
```

Step 2: Below the class, or after obtaining the callable,

```
api.add_resource(CuteKitty,'/api/kitty/meow',endpoint='meow',methods=['GET'])
```

Comment: But this doesn't work the way you think, for `GET /api/kitty/meow` it will just return whatever get(self) returns (empty dict) and ignore meow(self) output. At least for:
Flask-RESTful 0.3.10

Answer (score 0):

This can help; saves you the stress of unnecessarily writing new classes whose methods should belong to a single class

```
from flask_restful import (
    Resource,
    request
)
import logging

class AuthViews(Resource):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    logging.info("Entered the auth views...")

    def login(self):
        print("\n\t Login route....")


    def register(self):
        print("\n\t Register route....")
        

    def post(self):
        print("\n\t post-Data: ", request.data)
        print("\n\t url-Data: ", request.url)
        url = request.url
        if "login" in url:
            login = self.login()
        elif "register" in url:
            register = self.register()
        elif "forgot-password" in url:
            forgot_password = self.register()
        else:
            ...etc
```

When you're done, you could define all the routes concerned with this class as

```
auth_routes = ["/auth/login", "/auth/register", "/auth/forgot-password"]
```

Then in your app instantiation, you'd say;

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(AuthViews, *auth_routes)
```